# access a variable in an SWF file from another SWF file

Tags: flash, variables

OK, I'm an ActionScript noob. I can do "click here to go there" kind of stuff, all timeline scriptiing.

Then I had this project dumped in my lap (because I'm the "Flash Guy") and though I've read a bunch of stuff that sort of makes sense, I need someone to tell me exactly what to code where. I promise I will go back once this is over and learn real AS3, I've got the books and a good tutorial.

Here's the task. I have one SWF file (we'll call it parent.swf) that asks a user to input a name into a textfield (hospNameInput), and saves it to a variable (hName).

```
var hName:String;

hospNameInput.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, inputCapture1);
function inputCapture1(evt:Event):void
{
hName = hospNameInput.text;
}
```

I need to use the string variable "hName" in another SWF (child.swf, which is loaded by parent.swf) in order to add the name text to text boxes on many frames of my file. It's essentially a glorified slideshow with some interactivity on the frames, and they want to be able to personalize it for the people they are presenting to.

I have text boxes in child.swf that I'd like to populate with the text in the variable "hName" from parent.swf, like:

```
var frameHeader:String = "01 " + hName + " Today";
frameHeader1.text = frameHeader;
chartLabel.text = hName + " Analysis";
```

Like I said, I'm just a wimpy timeline coder. Can someone give me fairly explicit instructions for what to put in each SWF to get this to work?

I promise to read the books and learn to do this right, external .as files and all!!

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the variable through the content property of your Loader object. The content property should refer to the loaded swf's timeline directly.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#content

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having trouble with this, you can try the following steps...

- You have to create your text boxes with code. First add Input box to stage
- Load external SWF and treat it as MovieClip object.
- Add-child the text box (with saved Input) to the MovieClip (loaded SWF).

There is some example code to  try below. It adds an input box and when the user clicks a "load SWF" button it loads external SWF then adds textbox with a copy of the inputted text to it. To make a "load SWF" button just create a simple graphic like red square, convert to movieClip and give it the reference name "btn_load_SWF". (The code will still make it work like button). Also when creating text boxes by code you might want to take notes on X & Y positions you want them to appear. Use the Info tool (CTRL+I) to get hints of mouse/object positions on the stage. Anyway, All code goes in one frame..

```
//-- For later referencing of Child.swf as though it's MovieClip on stage named   "my_Child_Swf"
var my_Child_Swf:MovieClip;

//-- create User Input textbox
var input_txt:TextField = new TextField();
input_txt.type = "input";
input_txt.border = true;
input_txt.x = 50;
input_txt.y = 100;

//-- create string to hold User Input for passing onto a Child.swf textbox
var saved_text:String;

//-- create Name textbox for Child.swf (later will contain text of "saved_text") 
var name_txt:TextField = new TextField();
name_txt.type = "dynamic";
//name_txt.border = true;
name_txt.x = 10;
name_txt.y = 10;
name_txt.width = 50;

//-- Now add User Input box to screen 
stage.addChild(input_txt);

//-- load SWF
var swf_loader:Loader = new Loader(); 

//add loader object to stage BEFORE you do anything with external SWF..
stage.addChild(swf_loader);
btn_load_SWF.buttonMode = true;
btn_load_SWF.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, load_Child_SWF); 

//Button control function
function load_Child_SWF (event:MouseEvent) : void 
{ 
  saved_text = input_txt.text; //capture text as we begin load of Child SWF
  trace("input_txt is..." + saved_text); //trace is for testing/confirmation

  swf_loader.load ( new URLRequest ("Child.swf") );
  swf_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, Child_SWF_ready);
}  

function Child_SWF_ready (evt:Event) : void
{
  swf_loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, Child_SWF_ready); 
  swf_loader.x = stage.stageWidth / 2; 
  swf_loader.y = 200;

  //Treat the Loader contents (Child.swf) as a MovieClip named "my_Child_Swf"
  my_Child_Swf = swf_loader.content as MovieClip; 

  //Position of text when adding to Child SWF 
  //note: Its top-left corner is new X & Y point set to 0   
  name_txt.x = 10; //10 pixels from 0 point of Child SWF
  name_txt.y = 10;

  updateText(); //do instructions inside function "updateText"
  my_Child_Swf.addChild(name_txt); //add (updated) name text to Child SWF 

}

function updateText() : void
{
  name_txt.text = saved_text; //apply the saved_input String here
}
```

That should be enough to get you started. Other things to look into is how to set and embed fonts, set text sizes & colours and so on via code. For the record doing any coding in timeline is not the best way to work. I put all my code in one place, the .as file. I cant predict what will have happen when you shift to another frame & sets of code. That being said, this was tested from timeline and working. Thanks, VC:One